# Looking for ExecutorService with thread pool & minimal schedule latency

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection, executorservice, low-latency

Looking for `ExecutorService` like `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ForkJoinPool` but with minimal latency for adding tasks to work queue and dequeueing them for execution.

Highly desired for it to be CPU cache aware & with adjustable back off strategy and thread factory.

Or at least best examples of its parts to cook it.

Comment: With over 2k reputation, I think you should know what kind of questions are suitable for this site. This is not one of them. Please read the [FAQ] and [ask] page.

Comment: Willing to improve it... Please give me hint which part of it is most arguable.

Comment: How do you see this working? Say I guarantee that the minimum delay is 1 second. I have 4 CPUs and I schedule 5 tasks that each take 2 seconds to run. What happens now? I think it is _up to you_ to provide such guarantees if they are needed.

Comment: Have improved that part of question about min. latency.

Answer (score 4):

> minimal latency for adding tasks to work queue and dequeueing them for execution.

These libraries all have the same latency which is largely down to the hardware you have and the OS you have (as it does the thread scheduling)

There are no specific options which impact latency.

Other options include using;

- not using another thread, this has the minimum of latency, with a built in back off strategy ;)
- busy waiting consumer threads.
- slow the producer if the consumer can't keep up.

A couple of libraries you might be interested in is the Disruptor library which is an ultra low latency ring buffer which support busy waiting, and a library of mine, Java Chronicle which gives you persistence of all your messages/tasks almost for free and your consumer can be any amount behind your producer with next to no impact (e.g. many GB behind)

> CPU cache aware

Both of these libraries improve cache utilising by minimising the amount of garbage produced.  The ExecutorService produces some garbage but by far the largest delay is waking up the consumer thread.